# What is "o'clock" in English?

Tags: english, theoretical-linguistics, parts-of-speech, systemic-functional

Please don't say "adverb" because that is an *ad hoc* part of speech that means "anything that doesn't fit".

Certain words in the English language, from a functional perspective, map to counters in East Asian languages. Beyond measure words (cup of water, bottle of beer, etc...) or terms of venery (murder of crows, parliament of owls, etc...), words that describe base-10 number constructors, such as ten, hundred, thousand, million, etc... are counter nouns.

Would "o'clock", from the functional perspective, be considered a counter in East Asian languages? Or is it something completely different?

Comment: In both Chinese and Japanese (two of the major languages that use measure words extensively, telling the time uses a simple _noun_, just like in Romance languages, German and lots of other languages: you simply say it’s X _hours/time_, rather than ‘o’clock’. Not that that says anything at all about what _o’clock_ is in English.

Comment: The use of O'clock in English is a relic of when clocks weren't the ubiquitous, and only, means of defining time they are today. It was originally used to distinguish time defined from the clock from other means.

Comment: You mean particle? Adverb has a pretty clear definition.

Comment: Since when is "adverb" an _ad hoc_ part of speech that means "anything that doesn't fit"? Who's the author of that weird definition and what makes you think it contains at least a bit of common sense?

Comment: In the traditional "parts of speech" (before 20C grammarians got going) "adverb" was indeed the grab-it-all bag that anything that didn't fit elsewhere was put into.

Comment: It's funny, isn't it? Since o'clock means of the clock and one wonders which verb it adds to.

Answer (score 4):

Alas, it is an adverb. Your objection to garbage-categoriality is noted, but that problem stems from the ancient bad habit of thinking of a word of some part of speech being defined as modifying another word. Adverbs modify higher level constituents: predicates. POS classification is functional in the syntactic sense, describing the co-occurrence frames which allow the particular constituent. Also, "the three dogs which I saw" is not a noun, it is a phrase ultimately headed by a noun, so the co-occurrence frames don't literally refer to the POS of the word appearing right before the verb in the frame "___ ran away".

Comment: Both the OED and Wiktionary classify it as an adverb.

Comment: It may well be an adverb, but can you give some argumentation in support of this analysis? (I also don't understand the relevance of "the three dogs which I saw".)

Comment: "but that problem stems from the ancient bad habit of thinking of a word of some part of speech being defined as modifying another word." Your post was very good, but I had trouble understanding this part. What is the bad habit and why is it ancient?